# In Parse server get() method causes crash

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server, parse-cloud-code

I have a `find` query with `include` to get pointer data. It's working fine but if the pointer object does not exist then server crashes.

Here is my query:

```
var repliesQuery = new Parse.Query("Reply");
repliesQuery.include("author");
repliesQuery.find({
    useMasterKey: true
}).then(function(foundMessages) {
    var results = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < foundMessages.length; i++) {
        var rp = {};
        rp.title = foundMessages[i].get("title");
        rp.description = foundMessages[i].get("description");

        var author = foundMessages[i].get("author");
        rp.authorId = author.id;

        results.push(rp);
    }
    promise.resolve(results);
});
```

Everything works fine when the author exists, but if it does not exist then the server crashes.

I tried to add this:

```
if (author.hasOwnProperty('id')) {
    rp.authorId = author.id;
}
```

But still the issue is not resolved.

Is there any way we can fix this issue?

Comment: try `if(author){rp.authorId = author.id;}`

Comment: Server crashes? What does that mean? Which error happens where?

Comment: @Jost Iy throws an 503 error

Comment: In which exact line does the error occur?

Comment: `var author = foundMessages[i].get("author");
        rp.authorId = author.id;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's most likely because you're accessing a property of an `undefined` object, in this case `author`, in line

`rp.authorId = author.id`

Like Davi suggests, include a check if `author` exists.

```
var repliesQuery = new Parse.Query("Reply");
repliesQuery.include("author");
repliesQuery.find({
    useMasterKey: true
}).then(function(foundMessages) {
    var results = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < foundMessages.length; i++) {
        var rp = {};
        rp.title = foundMessages[i].get("title");
        rp.description = foundMessages[i].get("description");

        var author = foundMessages[i].get("author");
        if (author) {
            rp.authorId = author.id;
        }

        results.push(rp);
    }
    promise.resolve(results);
});
```

Your check

```
if (author.hasOwnProperty('id')) {
    rp.authorId = author.id;
}
```

also accesses a property of `author`, so again it would throw an error if `author` is `undefined`.